# Why am I getting this? "NameError: name 'Response' is not defined"

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get data from another of my servers. The other server is just an html file with "Hello World" I can reach my homepage fine, but when I go to `/farmdata`, I get this error:

> NameError: name 'Response' is not defined"

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/farmdata')
def farmdata():
    r = requests.get('http://74.114.75.91:8080')
    r.url
    r.encoding
    return Response(
        r.text,
        status=r.status_code,
        content_type=r.headers['content-type'],
    )

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=80, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Edit - to anyone else with the problem, this was the solution.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
```

Comment: `from flask import Response`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have never defined `Response`. If you want to use `flask.Response`, you either have to `import flask` and then access it via `flask.Response`, or `from flask import Response` and then simply use `Response`.

In your code, you import `Flask` from the `flask` module, and that's where you get `Flask` from. If you remove the `from flask import Flask` line, you'll get a `NameError` complaining about `Flask` not being defined as well.

In Python, a name is defined if:

- you defined it via variable assignment [or with a `def` or a `class` statement, which is pretty much the same] (like `app` in your example)
- you imported it from another module explicitly (like `Flask`)
- it's defined on startup (like `list`)

Comment: I've tried that. When I put in this
```
from flask import Flask, render_template, import Response
```
I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @TheCandyKing try to delete last `import` from your example

Comment: The correct syntax is either `import Module`,  `from Module import *`, `from Module import a, b, c`, `from Module import a as my_a, b, c, d as hello_world`. More on imports: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html, https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Answer (score -1):

Is there not a " ," too much before closing the brackets of the response?

Comment: Trailing commas are valid in Python. This has nothing to do wtih the `NameError`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, while like the others say it is not the error, I do like to have my code formatted correctly. 

I make enough mistakes already, I don't need to make more because of bad formatting